# Search tag name in XML Dom from user input and display the content in between- Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xmldom

I would like to ask how do find a tag name in XML dom from user input then loop through and display everything within it
if I enter 'unit', then it would display everything within the unit tag

eg.
XML

```
<course>
     <name>course name</name>
     <duration>3 years</duration>
     <unit>
          <title>Testing 1</title>
          <lecturer>
              <surname language="English">Lecturer</surname>
              <othernames language="English">1</othernames>
              <email>4567@hotmail.com</email>
          </lecturer>
     </unit>
     <unit>
          <title>Testing 2</title>
          <lecturer>
              <surname>Lecturer</surname>
              <othernames>2</othernames>
              <email>123@hotmail.com</email>
          </lecturer>
     </unit>
</course>
```

This is the Node js code I am using,

```
fs.readFile('course.xml', 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    // construct parser
    parser = new xmldom();
    // call method to parse document - not the type
    doc = parser.parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');

    userInput = readLineSync.question("Enter tag to be printed: ");

    // use DOM Node method
    targetNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName(userInput.toLowerCase());
    console.log("Tag " + userInput + " entered");

    for (i in targetNodes) {
        // process current ith node
        targetObj = targetNodes[i];
    
        // if it is the firstchild
        if (targetObj.firstChild) {
            // obtain the node value
            fcObj = targetObj.childNodes;
            parentObj = targetObj.parentNode;

            if (parentObj == null && count == 0){
                console.log("No identical tag found.");
            } else {
                count = 1;
                if (parentObj != null) {
                    // if (fcObj[count].nodeName === userInput) {
                        output = parentObj.getElementsByTagName(userInput)[count].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        console.log(output);
                    // }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The expect output if user enter 'unit'

```
Testing 1
Lecturer 1
4567@hotmail.com

Testing 2
Lecturer 2
123@hotmail.com
```

Comment: Is that always the same XML structure? Why is the value of `<surname>Lecturer</surname>` and `<othernames language="English">1</othernames>` output on the same line while the data of other elements is output on different lines? Is that something you are going to hard code in the code because you know the XML structure or something you want the code to infer?

Answer (score 0):

XML is a tree, if you want to output it as a list you need to flatten it - for example with a recursive function. Reduce the tree to a list based on the element nodes without an element child node.

```js
const dataSource = (new DOMParser).parseFromString(getXML(), 'text/xml');

const selectedTag = 'unit';
//const selectedTag = 'duration';

const targetNodes = [...dataSource.getElementsByTagName(selectedTag)]
  .map(
    (targetNode) => {
      return {
        name: targetNode.localName,
        descendants: getDescendantList(targetNode),
        textContent: targetNode.textContent
      }
    }
  );
  
//debug generated array of descendant lists 
console.log(targetNodes);  

// write output
const demo = document.getElementById('demo'); 
demo.textContent = targetNodes.map(
  (targetNodeData) => {
    if (targetNodeData.descendants.length > 0) {
      return targetNodeData.descendants.map(
        (data) =>  `${'  '.repeat(data.depth)} ${data.name}: ${data.textContent}`
      ).join('\n') + '\n';
    } else {
      return `${targetNodeData.name}: ${targetNodeData.textContent}\n\n`;
    }
  }
).join('');
  

function getDescendantList(parentNode, depth = 0) {
  return [...parentNode.childNodes]
    // filter for element nodes
    .filter(
       (node) => node.nodeType === node.ELEMENT_NODE
    )
    .reduce(
    (carry, node) => {
       // get descendant data
       const descendants = getDescendantList(node, depth + 1);
       // no descendant data, leaf node, add data
       if (descendants.length < 1) {
         carry.push(
           {
             depth, 
             name: node.localName,
             textContent: node.textContent
           }
         );
       } else {
         // add descendants to list
         carry.push(
           ...descendants
         );
       }
       return carry;
    },
    []
  );
}

function getElementChildren(parentNode) {
  return ;
}



function getXML() {
  return `<course>
     <name>course name</name>
     <duration>3 years</duration>
     <unit>
          <title>Testing 1</title>
          <lecturer>
              <surname language="English">Lecturer</surname>
              <othernames language="English">1</othernames>
              <email>4567@hotmail.com</email>
          </lecturer>
     </unit>
     <unit>
          <title>Testing 2</title>
          <lecturer>
              <surname>Lecturer</surname>
              <othernames>2</othernames>
              <email>123@hotmail.com</email>
          </lecturer>
     </unit>
</course>`
}
```

```html
<pre id="demo"></pre>
```